# How to separate words by comma in Google Actions and Alexa

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, actions-on-google

I am building a bot that will take a list from a user as input.
In my backend logic I split the list items by a comma, is there a way to make Google Actions and Amazon Alexa understand that the user is saying two different things and the Speech to Text needs to add a comma in between?

The last resort is the user saying the word comma, so it would be A comma B comma C.
My desired outcome is A {user pause for a second} B A {user pause for a second} C will become A,B,C

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that speech processing isn't good enough to determine if you're pausing due to enumerating items in a list, or if you're pausing to remember the other half of the name of the item you're trying to remember.

Consider, for example, if you're trying to order a hamburger with pickles, a cheeseburger with cheddar, and cheeseburger with fries. The human saying this might speak something like: "I'll have a hamburger with [pause] pickles [pause] a cheeseburger [pause] with cheddar and a cheeseburger with fries." In this case they won't pause before the final item (because they know what they want exactly), but might before the others because they're still pondering.

I don't know your system and if your items are or can use a controlled vocabulary, but being able to limit what your system can consider a distinct item helps you break it down into the list you need instead of using audible cues to break it down into the list items.. (In the example, we could say that "hamburger", "cheeseburger", and "fries" can be distinct orderable items, so can use those as cues for the list.)

Comment: So basically I will need some Entity name extraction on my list so that I can know which terms are which and possibly some kind of prediction algorithm to know with high probability that the "hamburger with pickles" is one product and not two.
Is that right?

Comment: I don't know what back-end you're using to process the text, but those are reasonable approaches, yes.